# Docker HostConfig Binds not adding directory to container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm using Docker in a Jenkins pipeline.

In the `Dockerfile`, the `WORKDIR` is specified like so:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/directory
```

Then in the Jenkins pipeline, the container is deployed like so:

```
stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        script {
            docker.image('deployscript:latest').withRun("""\
            -e 'IMAGE=${name}:${BUILD_ID}' \
            -e 'CNAME=${name}' \
            -e 'PORT=8000:80' \
            -e 'PORT=8000:443' \
            -e 'CONFIG={\"HostConfig\":{\"Binds\":[\"/local/home/certificates:/certificates\"]}}'""") { c ->
                sh "docker logs ${c.id}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The container is deployed but my problem is with the `CONFIG` parameter; the `/local/home/certificates` directory of the host machine is not being added to the container as a `certificates` directory. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to just be setting a bunch of environment variables.  The `docker.image().withRun()` invocation takes actual `docker run` parameters; you'd use `docker run -p` and `-v` options instead of your `PORT` and `CONFIG` environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will stop the existing container and run a new one with a new image, and it will mount the host certificates directory into the container:

```
stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        sh "docker stop ${IMAGE_NAME} || true && docker rm ${IMAGE_NAME} || true"
        sh "docker run -d \
            --name ${IMAGE_NAME} \
            --publish ${PORT}:443 \
            --mount type=bind,src=/local/home/certificates,dst=/certificates \
            ${IMAGE_NAME}:${BUILD_ID}"
    }
}
```